# multiple form modals on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I need help with the javascript. I'm trying to display a dynamic name inside the modal using multiple forms. Here is what I have, but it says "Are you sure you want to delete bob?" but I want it to display tom if I click on the delete tom button.

Forms:

```
<form role="form" id="formfield" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="bob" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id" value="45" /> 
<button type="button" name="btn" value="Delete" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tooltip-error no-border" style="padding:5px; width:30px; height:30px;" /><i class="fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i></button>
</form>

<form role="form" id="formfield" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="tom" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id" value="48" /> 
<button type="button" name="btn" value="Delete" id="submitBtn" data-    toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tooltip-error no-border" style="padding:5px; width:30px; height:30px;" /><i class="fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i></button>
</form>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Confirm Submit
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete <span id="deletename_id">?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger success">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
     $('#deletename_id').text($('#username').val());
});

$('#delete').click(function(){
    $('#formfield').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: First, you need to give each form a unique id, and you need to show a snippet of your backend code. I assume there must be loop to generate these *forms*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use `submitBtn` class, because you have two elements with same `id`.
Please try this:

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
    $('#deletename_id').text($(this).parents('form').find('input').eq(0).val());
});
```

Another method is to use this method:

```
$('#deletename_id').text($(this).parents('form').find('#username').val());
```

In both methods, you need to find the `form` which contains the `button` clicked and , then, you need to `find` the input.

```js
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {           
  $('#deletename_id').text($(this).parents('form').find('input').eq(0).val());
});

$('#delete').click(function(){
    $('#formfield').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="formfield" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="bob" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id" value="45" /> 
<button type="button" name="btn" class="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tooltip-error no-border"><i class="fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i>Delete</button>
</form>

<form role="form" id="formfield" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="tom" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id" value="48" /> 
<button type="button" name="btn" class="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tooltip-error no-border"><i class="fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i>Delete</button>
</form>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Confirm Submit
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to delete <span id="deletename_id"></span>?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger success">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would change the click handler to be `$('#deletename_id').text($(this).parents('form').find('#username').val());` - that way, if the order of the hidden elements changes, the handler can still find the correct value (or similarly, use a class for the input field desired)

Comment: what about multiple forms on the same page? $('.submitBtn').click(function() {           
$('#deletename_id').text($(this).('#formfield').find('#<?=$delete_name?>_id').val());
});

Comment: What about if inside a different form? How can you make the javascript unique for each form?

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: I don't know javascript, but something like this. Making formfield_1 dynamic. So each form will be named differently. formfield_1, formfield_2 and so on: <form role="form" id="formfield_1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">         $('.submitBtn').click(function() {          
$('#deletename_id').text($('#formfield_1').closest('form').find('#<?=$delete_name?>_id').val());
});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make javascript unique then you need to think  a bit dynamic like giving id in such a way that you can get different field data from different form with just changing a character while getting data.

What i want to mean is that as you can see in my code that I have appended '_1' and '_2' after your id's 'username' and 'delete_id'. Also I have used an advanced way of generating bootstrap modal. So that you don't need to write hole code by your self. You can get clear idea of this method from [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/).

Now, note that upon clicking the button I have called a method in which i have passed an id. If that id varies then I can get name on that id.

For testing purpose copy past any form and change the digit after '_' in every id to your favourite digit and also put that in brackets after 'deleteForm' function call as a parameter.

```js
function deleteForm(formid) {
  var name = $('#username_' + formid).val();
  console.log(name);
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Confirm Submit',
    message: 'Are you sure you want to delete '+name+' ?',
    buttons: [{
      label: 'Cancel',
      action: function(dialog) {
        dialog.close();
      }
    }, {
      label: 'Delete',
      cssClass : 'btn btn-danger',
      action: function(dialog) {
        // Do whatever you want to do here
        console.log('Do whatever you want to do here');
        dialog.close();
      }
    }]
  });

}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>





<form role="form" id="formfield_1" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username_1" value="bob" />
  <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id_1" value="45" />
  <button type="button" name="btn" value="Delete" id="submitBtn_1" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tooltip-error no-border" style="padding:5px; width:30px;height:30px;" onclick="deleteForm(1)" /><i class="fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i>
  </button>
</form>

<form role="form" id="formfield_2" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username_2" value="tom" />
  <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id_2" value="48" />
  <button type="button" name="btn" value="Delete" id="submitBtn_2" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tooltip-error no-border" style="padding:5px; width:30px; height:30px;" onclick="deleteForm(2)" /><i class="fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```